# Using a variable name to create an object in PHP

Tags: php, class

I came across this code written by the previous developer:

```
$model_class = 'Resource';
$model = new $model_class("data");
```

I decided to change it to:

```
$model = new Resource("data");
```

The latter caused the program to stop working. What is the difference between the two? What is going on in the first code example?

Comment: I'll bet if you removed `$model_class = 'Resource';` you broke something else in the script

Comment: Put the error message

Comment: Those have the same working result when instantiating a new class. It must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Ctrl+F `$model_class`. Think.

Comment: Think. "When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do exactly the same thing.

Consequently, some other part of your code relies on the fact that `$model_class` was set to `'Resource'`.

Comment: After reading the responses I feel a bit dumb to not have thought of that. Thanks all.